# I have only 2 records in my table but it fetches 4 records from database

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to print the values from database using with crystal report.

my code is here.

```
       private void frmPrintBill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

        try
        {
            SqlCon = objDB.DBConnection();

            Query = "Select p.billno, p.productid, p.productname, p.customerrate, p.quantity, p.amount, p.alert, s.noofitems, s.totamount from tblBill as p inner join tblBillsub as s on p.billno = s. billno  where p.billno= '101' ";

            StrPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Reports\\CrystalReport1.rpt";
            ReportDocument ObjRepDoc = new ReportDocument();
            SqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, SqlCon);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Clear();
            SqlDa.Fill(dt);


            CrystalReport1 rep1 = new CrystalReport1();
            ObjRepDoc.Load(StrPath);
            ObjRepDoc.SetDataSource(dt);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ObjRepDoc;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
           }

        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

      }
```

In my database table there are two records only available for the particular billno. But it fetch 4 records. Why??
Kindly support me..

Comment: bill 101 has two the same records in tblBillsub and you are using inner join

Comment: ok. what to do get the exact result

Comment: maybe you can try `left join`

Comment: I tried out... but getting same result

Comment: what if you only select from one table?

Comment: use distinct...

Answer (score 0):

In crystal report you can also use:

```
suppress if duplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 4 records because of the inner join. It is a cartesian product of both tables.

I understand you want to group your report by some product field and use the group header to show the product fields.

If you leave the details section empty, you will see only two records. But you can use the details section to show the bill fields.